# Python, BeautifulSoup - Extracting part of a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a side project to see if I can predict the wins on a website, however this is one of the first times I've used BeautifulSoup and I'm not entirely sure on how to cut a string down to size.

Here is the code, I basically want to grab the information that holds where it crashed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

html = urlopen('https://www.csgocrash.com/game/1/1287324').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for section in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"row panel radius"}):
    crashPoint = section.findChildren()[2]
    print crashPoint
```

Upon running it, I get this as the output.

```
<p> <b>Crashed At: </b> 1.47x </p>
```

I want to basically only want to grab the number value, which would require me to cut from both sides, I just don't know how to go about doing this, as well as removing the HTML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `Crashed At` label by text and get the *next sibling*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for section in soup.findAll('div', {"class":"row panel radius"}):
    crashPoint = section.find("b", text="Crashed At: ").next_sibling.strip()
    print(crashPoint)  # prints 1.47x
```

---

Also, not sure if you need a loop in this case since there is a single `Crashed At` value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

html = urlopen('https://www.csgocrash.com/game/1/1287324').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

section = soup.find('div', {"class":"row panel radius"})
crashPoint = section.find("b", text="Crashed At: ").next_sibling.strip()
print(crashPoint)
```

Comment: Seem to be getting an error now                                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/CSGOCrash/2xProgram.py", line 8, in <module>
    crashPoint = section.find("b", text="Crashed At: ").next_sibling.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @BenParry I think you need to explicitly specify a parser, updated the answer.

Comment: works for me.  running it in python 2.7.11+ on  ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @BenParry okay, what if you do `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` and then try again? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, Just updated it and that did the trick greatly, thanks :). Final question though, is it possible to remove the x after the value so I can then store that value for later usage?

Comment: @BenParry glad to hear it worked for you. You can just replace it `crashPoint = crashPoint.replace("x", "")`.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for the help